# Gitlab CI/CD using ssh / knownhosts error

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, gitlab-runner

I'm trying to use gitlab CI/CD to auto deploy my code, after push on an specific branch (in my case 'staging' branch)

after push on 'staging' branch I see following error on jobs section in gitlab UI:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.0.0 (xxxxxx)
  on deploy xxxxxx
Preparing the "ssh" executor
00:36
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh command Connect() error: ssh Dial() error: ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key is unknown
```

I can see gitlab from my VM and gitlab-runner registered successfully before.

I've also created ssh key and add it to gitlab-runner installation steps.

Comment: The `Dial()` part suggests that this is using Go's ssh implementation. The "known hosts" stuff is, well, what [VonC said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593914/1256452). Command-line ssh can be told "trust on first use" and that's actually the usual default, so if you're connect to `gitlab.com` for the *first time*, ssh will read the data coming from whoever answers at `gitlab.com` and save it in your `.ssh/known_hosts` file. *Without* "trust on first use", though, you must preload the correct host key.

Comment: For the usual Go ssh `Dial()` function, however, the host key is handled by a `HostKeyCallback` function (see [the `ClientConfig` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig) and [the `HostKeyCallback` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#HostKeyCallback)). What gitlab-ci-runner uses, I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check what SSH URL is used in your case.

Something like `git@gitlab.com:me/myProject` would look for [gitlab.com SSH host keys fingerprints](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints) in an `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Make sure to add first in gitlab-runner server the following to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`:

```
gitlab.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIAfuCHKVTjquxvt6CM6tdG4SLp1Btn/nOeHHE5UOzRdf
gitlab.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsj2bNKTBSpIYDEGk9KxsGh3mySTRgMtXL583qmBpzeQ+jqCMRgBqB98u3z++J1sKlXHWfM9dyhSevkMwSbhoR8XIq/U0tCNyokEi/ueaBMCvbcTHhO7FcwzY92WK4Yt0aGROY5qX2UKSeOvuP4D6TPqKF1onrSzH9bx9XUf2lEdWT/ia1NEKjunUqu1xOB/StKDHMoX4/OKyIzuS0q/T1zOATthvasJFoPrAjkohTyaDUz2LN5JoH839hViyEG82yB+MjcFV5MU3N1l1QL3cVUCh93xSaua1N85qivl+siMkPGbO5xR/En4iEY6K2XPASUEMaieWVNTRCtJ4S8H+9
gitlab.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFSMqzJeV9rUzU4kWitGjeR4PWSa29SPqJ1fVkhtj3Hw9xjLVXVYrU9QlYWrOLXBpQ6KWjbjTDTdDkoohFzgbEY=
```

That will skip manual fingerprint confirmation in SSH.
In other words, no more "`knownhosts: key is unknown`".

---

Note that with [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#new-links-to-ssh-fingerprints) (August 2022), you will have an easier time finding those:

> ### New links to SSH fingerprints
>
> Your GitLab SSH fingerprints are now easier to find, thanks to new links on the SSH configuration page and in the documentation.
>
> Thank you [Andreas Deicha](https://gitlab.com/TrueKalix) for your contribution!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_3/manage-ssh-fingerprint.png -- New links to SSH fingerprints]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#verify-that-you-can-connect) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21683).

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm using a completely different gitlab (for example gitlab.company.com) server for the company. can you help me, how can I get ssh host keys fingerprints for this private gitlab server?

Comment: @shahabvalizade Usually, the first ssh git@gitlab.company.com will prompt you to accept the key fingerprint, and update the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`  automatically. But you have to ask an admin to confirm those are the correct ones.

Comment: I'm Stack. This is not working for me. I don't know why.

Comment: @HasiburRahman Then it is best to describe your issue in a separate question.

Comment: I am also getting same error. Can you pls provide a solution 


Error: "ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh command Connect() error: ssh Dial() error: ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key is unknown" @VonC

Comment: @AnirbanDas At first glance, the solution seems to be the same as the one written above. Please ask a separate question if it is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

you should add below line to `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` under `[[runner.ssh]]` section corresponding to your ssh runner:

`known_hosts_file = "/home/<gitlab-runner-user>/.ssh.known_hosts"`

Answer (score 0):

For people who still encounter this issue: in our case the cause was a difference between the host name in the known_host file and the one in the toml file. They must be both fully qualified or both non qualified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).